# Hide or shorten part of an arrow when using double copy shadow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to generate a flowchart using Tikz, and I want to use double copy shadow to represent repetition of the same calculation several times with different inputs. The problem is that when I apply double copy shadow to the arrows, the arrows appear over the nodes.

This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shadows}
\tikzset{
    boxSolidLine/.style = { fill=white, draw=black, thick, centered },
    shadowbox/.style={boxSolidLine, double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=1ex}},
    arrowshadow/.style = { thick, color=black, ->, >=Triangle,double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=1ex}},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto]
            % Place nodes
            \node [shadowbox] (node1) {Node 1};
            \node [shadowbox, right= of node1] (node2) {Node 2};
            \node [shadowbox, right= of node2] (node3) {Node 3};
            % Draw edges
            \draw [arrowshadow] (node1) -- (node2);
            \draw [arrowshadow] (node2) -- (node3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Test figure.}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

As you can observe, the lines are over the nodes at the beginning of the arrows. I have tried to use layers but I could not manage to use them with the double copy shadow arrows. In addition, why only the first arrow is thick, and not the other two?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, using layers might be the way to go here.

Keep in mind that basically, although to calculate the locations of the objects we need to go 1 -> 2 -> 3. We would really love to be drawing everything backwards.

Therefore, I set 3 layers `node1ground`, `node2ground`, `node3ground`, and I place the order of the layers using `\pgfsetlayers` so that they are drawn ending with `node1ground` on top of the other layers

Here is my solution using layers. No need to add any other package, no need to redraw things multiple times :)

(Note that `foreground` and `background` can be removed, but it makes it easier to see which one is on top and which one is on the bottom, since their names are self-explanatory)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shadows}
\tikzset{
    boxSolidLine/.style = { fill=white, draw=black, thick, centered },
    shadowbox/.style={boxSolidLine, double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=1ex}},
    arrowshadow/.style = { thick, color=black, ->, >=Triangle,double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=1ex}},
}


\pgfdeclarelayer{node3ground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{node2ground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{node1ground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,node3ground,node2ground,node1ground,foreground}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto]
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{node1ground} %On top
                \node [shadowbox] (node1) {Node 1};
            \end{pgfonlayer}

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{node2ground} %On middle
                \node [shadowbox, right= of node1] (node2) {Node 2};
            \end{pgfonlayer}

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{node3ground} %On bottom
                \node [shadowbox, right= of node2] (node3) {Node 3};
                \draw [arrowshadow] (node2) -- (node3);
            \end{pgfonlayer}

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{node2ground} %On middle, after node 2 is draw
                \draw [arrowshadow] (node1) -- (node2);
            \end{pgfonlayer}

            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Test figure.}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can redraw the nodes in the correct order (I also added thick to the shadow style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shadows}
\tikzset{
    boxSolidLine/.style = { fill=white, draw=black, thick, centered },
    shadowbox/.style={boxSolidLine, double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=1ex}},
    arrowshadow/.style = { thick, color=black, ->, >=Triangle,double copy shadow={thick,shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=1ex}},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto]
            % Place nodes
            \node [shadowbox]                  (node1) {Node 1};                
            \node [shadowbox, right= of node1] (node2) {Node 2};                     
            \node [shadowbox, right= of node2] (node3) {Node 3};

            \draw [arrowshadow] (node2) -- (node3);

            \node [shadowbox, right= of node1] (node2) {Node 2};

            \draw [arrowshadow] (node1) -- (node2);

            \node [shadowbox] (node1) {Node 1};

            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Test figure.}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]